# Combine Two Similar Numeric Class Implementations

Tags: java, inheritance, numbers, abstract-class

I have two classes which pretty much implement the same operations for two different numeric types (except for the `getHexadecimalValue()` method):

```
public class IntegerType
{
    private int value;

    public IntegerType()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public String getHexadecimalValue()
    {
        int integerValue = (int) getValue();

        String hexadecimal = ValueConversions.toHexadecimal(integerValue);

        return hexadecimal;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FloatingPointType
{
    private float value;

    public FloatingPointType()
    {
        value = 0;
    }

    public void setValue(float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public float getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public String getHexadecimalValue()
    {
        float floatingValue = (float) getValue();

        int intBits = Float.floatToRawIntBits(floatingValue);

        return ValueConversions.toHexadecimal(intBits);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what the best way would be to reduce this redundancy by e.g. defining a superclass called `NumberType` like this:

```
public abstract class NumberType
{
    protected Number value;

    public NumberType()
    {
        setValue(0);
    }

    public void setValue(Number value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Number getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract String getHexadecimalValue();
}
```

Now the problem is that any number can be passed to my inheriting classes but I only want to accept `ints` and `floats` respectively while still keeping redundancy to a minimum:

```
public class IntegerType extends NumberType
{
    @Override
    public String getHexadecimalValue()
    {
        // Crashes on runtime if the value doesn't happen to be of the expected type
        int integerValue = (int) getValue();

        String hexadecimal = ValueConversions.toHexadecimal(integerValue);

        return hexadecimal;
    }
}
```

Can this be done by still keeping proper type checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
public abstract class NumberType<T extends Number> {
    protected T value;

    public NumberType(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract String getHexadecimalValue();
}

public class FloatingPointType extends NumberType<Float> {
    public FloatingPointType() {
        super(0f);
    }

    public String getHexadecimalValue() {
        return ValueConversions.toHexadecimal(Float.floatToRawIntBits(value));
    }
}
```

---

Note: Float and Integer, both class has static `toHexString` methods which you can directly use if you are comfortable to use them.

> 1. [public static String toHexString(float f)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toHexString%28float%29)
> 2. [public static String toHexString(int i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

Comment: The `toHexString` method for floats doesn't do what I want so I need my own (32 bit hexadecimal representation). Is it also possible to do the 0 initialization of `value` in the superclass? I think not but maybe I'm missing something. Also note that the cast is now redundant. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do `0` initialization in superclass. But I have updated the code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with overloading

for example:

```
public abstract class NumberType
{
    private Number value;

    public NumberType()
    {
        setValue(0);
    }

    public void setValue(float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Number getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract String getHexadecimalValue();
}
```

You can also add then:

```
public int getIntValue()
{
        return value.intValue();
}

public float getFloatValue()
{
        return value.floatValue();
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of making 2 different subclasses of `NumberType` then? Besides using your approach, `new IntegerType().setValue(2);` is possible, which will be a compilation error in original question.

Comment: Maybe I understood question wrong, but i thought he wanted to get rid of the IntegerType and FloatType class. combine them both in one class: NumberType

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, setValue(Number value) must not allow entering any value but float in FloatingPointType and setValue(Number value) must not allow entering any value but int in IntegerType. You can check by using intValue() and floatValue() methods in class Number and throw exception if inappropriate value entered. [Number class methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#floatValue%28%29)

It would be something like this in setValue(Number value) of IntegerType

`if(value.intValue()!= value)
 throw new IllegalArgumentException()`